# My php script to download a file is just displaying it in browser when code is running in cloud, yet works fine on my local server

Tags: php, file, browser, download, header

I am trying to download a file using php script. The file is in a database. I extracted the file content and I am printing it out with a header to download.
It works fine on my localhost but when code is running in the cloud, it then displays the file in the browser instead of downloading it.
I did search all similar cases, and I am doing what the best solutions recommend.
Here is my code:

```
      $fcontent = $row->content;

      header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
      header("Pragma:public");
      header("Content-Description:File Transfer");
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:Binary");
      header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"$fname\"");
      header("Content-Length:" . $fsize);
      header("Expires:0");
      header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate");

      ob_clean();
      flush();
      
      print ($fcontent);
      die();
```

Comment: have you checked if the cloud server is adding any other headers in the response, or overwriting the ones you've specified?

Comment: Good PHP Programmers never `die()` however they do know when to `exit;` :)

Comment: Where is the code that offers this download to the user? E.g. is it a HTML5 download link? Does that element differ between environments?